# Как сравнивать строки .Shell

Tags: linux, shell

Написал скрипт простенький  под android.Он проверяет значения `mDataActivity`

```
#!/system/bin/sh

su

b=mDataActivity=3

a=$(dumpsys telephony.registry | grep mDataActivity | head -1)

if [ "$b" = "$a" ]
then 
 echo " true "
else
echo "false"
echo $a # смотрим какое значение в переменной для  проверки
fi
```

У меня  выходит false , даже когда  `$a = $b`. В чем моя ошибка ?

Answer (score 3):

так, наверно, попроще будет:

```
if dumpsys telephony.registry | grep -q "mDataActivity=3"; then
  echo "true"
else
  echo "false"
fi
```

---

вообще от сравнения строк **средствами оболочки** лучше воздержаться. ведь часто при этом могут возникнуть «коллизии», например, из-за наличия какого-нибудь «лишнего» пробела.

а при использовании возможностей программы *grep* легко всё это учесть — с помощью регулярных выражений.

приведённый выше шаблон

```
if программа-или-команда | grep -q регулярное-выражение; then ...
```

даёт значительно более надёжный и предсказуемый результат, чем попытки (непосредственного сравнения динамически получаемых строк) вида

```
if [ строка1 = строка2 ]; then ...
```

Comment: Ваш код отлично составлен !  
Видно вы далеко не новичек )   не могли бы пояснить почему  у меня  была ошибка ?

Comment: @user238026, вероятнее всего, у вас не совпадают значения строк ввиду того, что строки не совпадают. например, благодаря наличию пробелов и т.п.

Comment: @user238026, скорее всего в приведенном вами коде вверху вы не окавычили значение переменной, и интерпретатор подумал нечто иное (`b = mDataActivity = 3`).